# How to stream music from one android device to another?

Tags: bluetooth, music, streaming

I have an android tablet in my car which is connected to my car's Audio System. My Phone has my most recent music collection on it. How can I directly stream music from my phone to my tablet, without having to copy the files or the devices being on the same wifi network? Can this be done with bluetooth? Both devices are running Jelly Bean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This app could do the trick:

[Bluetooth Music Player Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ilumnis.btplayerfree)

You need to install it on both Android devices and pair them. Then put the tablet in `ListenMUSIC over Blueetooth` mode and the the phone in `shareMUSIC over Bluetooth` mode.

Comment: From Illuminati's store... er... I said from Ilumnis one?

Comment: @kokbira Yes, from Ilumnis as a developer/publisher on the Google Play store. The free version is enough.

Comment: extremely buggy program :(

Comment: This does not answer the original question. Bluetooth Music Player Free apparently only receives song _names_, and tries to locate and play the file on the "receiving" devices. So it requires to copy files beforehand, which the original question ruled out.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from "Bluetooth music player" (mentioned in above answer), you may also try [SoundSeeder speaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kattwinkel.android.soundseeder.speaker&hl=en) or [SoundSeeder Music player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kattwinkel.android.soundseeder.player&hl=en). As i remember, at first you should pair the devices. From the description of *SoundSeeder Music player:*

> Soundseeder turns all your devices into into wireless speakers. Play your music louder and share it with your friends.
>   All connected devices (Android, Windows, Linux, Raspberry Pi, ...) play the music in sync as one large sound system.

*SoundSeeder speaker* is

> a speaker-only version of the SoundSeeder Music Player and was designed for devices running Android 2.2 - 4.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to do that. But I did a lot of research and got a way. Has several delay, connection and root problems, but apparently works. For this you will need to have the "AirAudio" application installed on the server and the "AllConnect" receiver. Then you open AirAudio on the home screen and then open AllConnect, press on your device, then on sources and choose the server, then choose the streaming mp3. The problem is that the delay is very large and another defect is that to transmit only the sound of the system of the android server you should have root on the phone ... I also tried the receiver of the streaming being the VLC, was less delayed but still So it's uncomfortable.