# Can I use my spare android phone as a Bluetooth speaker?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing, headphone-jack

Actually, I have a spare android phone which is connected to my old speaker system. I wanted to connect to that phone via Bluetooth as if I'm connected to a Bluetooth speaker.
So that, I can route audio to the speakers using any device connected to that spare phone (Indirectly giving the Bluetooth functionality to the old speaker system)

**Edit**: I saw the related questions, those questions needed any working method that solves it. I don't want to use any third-party app like a music player or anything. I just want the spare android phone to be connected as an audio source to my phone.

The first image is the screenshot of a Bluetooth headphone connected to my phone. I want the same settings as "Media Audio" when I'm connected to spare android phone.

[image: This is the screenshot of a Bluetooth headphone connected to my phone. I want the same settings as "Media Audio" when I'm connected to spare android phone.]

The second image is the screenshot of Bluetooth settings when connected to the android phone which is currently being detected as a phone and I want that to be shown as a Bluetooth Audio device.
[image: Screenshot of Bluetooth settings when connected to spare android phone]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stream music from one android device to another?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79150/how-to-stream-music-from-one-android-device-to-another)

Comment: @alecxs I've edited the question with the exact requirement.